# iOS reordering table view rows without delete button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've to reordering `UITableView` rows without show the default red minus button because I need to show my custom image and I don't need to remove cell from `UITableView`. Is there a way for reordering rows even if table is not in editing mode ?

[image]

Comment: "Is there a way for reordering rows even if table is not in editing mode ?" No, but there is a way to be in editing mode without showing the default red minus button.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will need to add this delegate method to not show the delete button

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

Comment: and there is a way to remove the left padding ?

Comment: Sure, just add another delegate method: - tableView: shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath: and return NO.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should check out the followings:
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/reordertableviewcontroller
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/reorderabletableview